# Display value after using getRequestDispatcher() in java

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
<jsp:useBean id="customers" type="Customers" scope="session" />
<jsp:getProperty name="name" property="fullName" />
<%= customers.getFullName() %>
<jsp:getProperty name="address" property="address" />
<%= customers.getAddress() %>
<jsp:getProperty name="city" property="city" />
<%= customers.getCity() %>
```

in Servlet file

```
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
disp.forward(request, response);
```

The problems are the home.jsp not displaying any output or errors.

Comment: is the session being created in Servlet ?

Comment: It have session by using 
request.setAttribute("Customers", objCustomers);
in the servlet

Comment: shouldn't you use , HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); and then  request.setAttribute("Customers", objCustomers);